# Eclipse and Pydev: Global "Run Configuration" for all files

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I just started trying out Pydev and Eclipse together for a small project.

My problem is, whenever I click 'run' on the entry point file of the project, it runs fine.

But, whenever I'm on a different file (not the entry point), it asks me to create a new run configuration for that file, when I just want it to start at the entry point.

What is the way to do this, because I've messed around in the properties for a while to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've just one "main" entry point, you could just set Eclipse to always run the last launched configuration.

http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/always-rundebug-the-last-launched-class-instead-of-the-selected-one-in-eclipse/

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept once the counter has depleted. But, how does it know which file to run? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: By default it tries to launch the currently opened file, and if it doesn't know how to launch it, it'll popup the "Run configuration" dialog.

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea: assign a key combination for `Relaunch last pydev launch` command. This way, one can have the benefits without changing global behavior (which can be inconvenient when working with multiple projects).

Comment: What a relieve. Thanx.